# Is Socket FD's are specific to a linux Process?

Tags: linux, sockets

I wrote a simple program in linux where it creates the socket id(got socket FD as 3), prints it and close it. Just before closing it will wait for user input. I started one more program instance in different shell. Second program also created socket but got same socket FD i.e., 3.
Then i extended the program to create two sockets in the same program. Now i got socket FD as 3 and 4.

Now my doubt is whether Socket FD values are specific to a process? If so, how does select call will correctly identifies which socket got the data?

Answer (score 1):

File Descriptors are unique to a running instance of a program - so your results are correct.  Since they are unique, select() also will be fine.

Comment: The select() call is also process-specific, so having the same FDs in different processes should be okay.

Comment: Since FDs are unique to a process, so you should be able to look at the returned value of the select() and identify which socket has data to be read. Please note that you pass an fd set to select() and the select() returns the fd set and sets the fd that has an event.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Based on this, i have one more query. I created, a socket and binded to so and so port. Now i killed the process without closing the socket. Now i tried to create another socket and binded with same port. But bind api returned error like port is already binded. So how i can close the socket which is part of already killed process?

Comment: Patience - the only way for it to go away now is for the OS to clean it up when it sees that there are no processes attached.  All you can do is wait.